# How can I access the text content for the next tag in xml?

Tags: java, xml

I have the following code:

```
    public String depRel() throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException, ClassNotFoundException,
        ClassCastException {
    String xmlString = Features.dependencyGraph();
    ;

    String result = "";
    String dependent = "";
    String governor = "";
    String type = "";

    // System.out.println("A value is :" + xmlString);
    // aici il convertesc ca sa il pot citi ca si xml
    Document document = convertStringToDocument(xmlString);
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("dependencies");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node node = nList.item(temp);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement1 = (Element) node;

        }
        NodeList nodesDocPart = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nodesDocPart.getLength(); temp2++) {

            Node n = nodesDocPart.item(temp2);

            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element el1 = (Element) n;
                type = el1.getAttribute("type");
            }

            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////sentence/////////////////////////////////////////////
            NodeList nodesSentencePart = n.getChildNodes();
            for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < nodesSentencePart.getLength(); temp3++) {
                Node sentence = nodesSentencePart.item(temp3);
                if (sentence.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement4 = (Element) sentence;
                    if (eElement4.getTagName().equals("dependent")) {
                        dependent = eElement4.getTextContent();
                    }
                    if (eElement4.getTagName().equals("governor")) {
                        governor = eElement4.getTextContent();


enter code here
```

And the next xml format which describe a dependency graph for a sentence.
The sentence is:The production of human immunodeficiency virus type 1 (HIV-1) progeny was followed in the U937 promonocytic cell line after stimulation either with retinoic acid or PMA, and in purified human monocytes and macrophages.

```
<dependencies style="typed">
  <dep type="det">
    <governor idx="2">production</governor>
    <dependent idx="1">The</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nsubjpass">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="2">production</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="case">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="3">of</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="4">human</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="compound">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="5">immunodeficiency</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="compound">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="6">virus</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nmod:of">
    <governor idx="2">production</governor>
    <dependent idx="7">type</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nummod">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="8">1</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="punct">
    <governor idx="10">HIV-1</governor>
    <dependent idx="9">-LRB-</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="appos">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="10">HIV-1</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="punct">
    <governor idx="10">HIV-1</governor>
    <dependent idx="11">-RRB-</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="dep">
    <governor idx="7">type</governor>
    <dependent idx="12">progeny</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="auxpass">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="13">was</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="case">
    <governor idx="20">line</governor>
    <dependent idx="15">in</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="det">
    <governor idx="20">line</governor>
    <dependent idx="16">the</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="compound">
    <governor idx="20">line</governor>
    <dependent idx="17">U937</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="20">line</governor>
    <dependent idx="18">promonocytic</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="compound">
    <governor idx="20">line</governor>
    <dependent idx="19">cell</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nmod:in">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="20">line</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="case">
    <governor idx="22">stimulation</governor>
    <dependent idx="21">after</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nmod:after">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="22">stimulation</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="dep">
    <governor idx="26">acid</governor>
    <dependent idx="23">either</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="case">
    <governor idx="26">acid</governor>
    <dependent idx="24">with</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="26">acid</governor>
    <dependent idx="25">retinoic</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nmod:with">
    <governor idx="22">stimulation</governor>
    <dependent idx="26">acid</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="cc">
    <governor idx="26">acid</governor>
    <dependent idx="27">or</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="nmod:with">
    <governor idx="22">stimulation</governor>
    <dependent idx="28">PMA</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="conj:or">
    <governor idx="26">acid</governor>
    <dependent idx="28">PMA</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="punct">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="29">,</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="cc">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="30">and</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="case">
    <governor idx="34">monocytes</governor>
    <dependent idx="31">in</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="34">monocytes</governor>
    <dependent idx="32">purified</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="amod">
    <governor idx="34">monocytes</governor>
    <dependent idx="33">human</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="conj:and">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="34">monocytes</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="cc">
    <governor idx="34">monocytes</governor>
    <dependent idx="35">and</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="conj:and">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="36">macrophages</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="conj:and">
    <governor idx="34">monocytes</governor>
    <dependent idx="36">macrophages</dependent>
  </dep>
  <dep type="punct">
    <governor idx="14">followed</governor>
    <dependent idx="37">.</dependent>
      </dep>
```

If I am at the tag "governor" how can I access the tag "dependent"?Because I want to obtain all governors and all dependents for a word.How can I make it?

Comment: `I want to obtain all governors and all dependents for a word` , what is `word` here ? Is it text of `governor` node?

Comment: The word is the curent word from the sentence that i will parse.I must retain the sentence too and for each word from the sentence to find the governors and the dependents

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have a collection of `governor/dependent/word`s.
You could use the below code to get a collection of such classes - I termed `GovernorDependentNode`

```
class GovernorDependentNode
{
    Node governor;
    Node dependent;
    String word;
}

List<GovernorDependentNode> getNodes( String word, InputSource is )
{
    List<GovernorDependentNode> gdNodes = new ArrayList<GovernorDependentNode>();
    try
    {

        Object govs = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("//dep/governor[.='" + word + "']", is, XPathConstants.NODESET );
        if ( govs != null )
        {
            NodeList gNodes = (NodeList)govs;
            for ( int i = 0; i < gNodes.getLength(); i++ )
            {
                GovernorDependentNode gdNode = new GovernorDependentNode();
                Node gNode = gNodes.item(i);
                gdNode.governor = gNode;
                gdNode.word = word;
                NodeList childNodes = gNode.getParentNode().getChildNodes();
                for ( int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++ )
                {
                    Node n = childNodes.item(j);
                    if ( n.getNodeName().equals( "dependent" ) )
                    {
                        gdNode.dependent = n;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                gdNodes.add( gdNode );

            }
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return gdNodes;
}
```

Use the method like:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) );
List<GovernorDependentNode> nodes = getNodes( "yourWord", is );
```

The method `getNodes` first gets the `governor` nodes for the given word using xpath : `//dep/governor[.='word']`.

There can be several , for example for the word `following` there are 9 nodes, so the `dependent` nodes should be obtained for each of them, and a class is constructed using the information - governor , dependent nodes and the given word.

In order to print the list of nodes, you could use:

```
List<GovernorDependentNode> nodes = getNodes( "followed", inputSource );
for ( GovernorDependentNode node : nodes )
{
        System.out.println( "Word : " + node.word );
        System.out.println( "Governor : " + node.governor.getTextContent() );
        System.out.println( "Dependent : " + node.dependent.getTextContent());

}
```

Output is :

```
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : production
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : was
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : line
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : stimulation
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : ,
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : and
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : monocytes
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : macrophages
Word : followed
Governor : followed
Dependent : .
```

Comment: And I shouldn't parse the xmlString in an xml file?Because when I am calling the metod like Input source is=new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)) the compiler knows that xmlString is not an XML?It is just a String in xml format

Comment: The compiler doesn't know if it is xml or not. If the string is not in xml format, the line `XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate` will throw an exception. You can check if the string is xml or not before passing it to the method.

Comment: When I run this code an exception appear at this line:         Object govs = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("//dep/governor[.='" + word + "']", is,XPathConstants.NODESET);

Comment: What is the exception ? Can you post atleast some of the stacktrace?

Comment: Oh, ok..now I saw your comment:Thank you!I will try to verify if my string is in an xml format

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 156; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in trailing section.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: This is the exception

Comment: Now it worked because it was a mistacke in xmlString but I don't know how can I saw the result of InputSource is = new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) );
List<GovernorDependentNode> nodes = getNodes( "yourWord", is );?How can I display it?

Comment: I have tried to display in this way: public void depRel() throws ClassNotFoundException,
   ClassCastException, IOException {
  String xmlString = dependencyGraph();
  InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
  List<GovernorDependentNode> nodes = getNodes("followed", is);
  for(int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++){
  System.out.println(nodes.get(i).toString());}
 }

Comment: But something like that appear in the console:licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@26653222
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@3532ec19
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@68c4039c
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@ae45eb6
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@59f99ea
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@27efef64
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@6f7fd0e6
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@47c62251
licenta1.Analyze$GovernorDependentNode@3e6fa38a; licenta1 is the package and Analyze is the class

Comment: @Nadd I updated my answer. See in the last, on how to display it.

Comment: Thank you.Now it worked.I have many sentences in an XML and I parsed it.For each sentence I must do that.Can I serialized it or to use some method because I'm spending many time to process all sentences.Have you an idea about how I can proceed?The classic mode is to process each sentence and to run the parser every time.How can I do in another way?

Comment: You can do something like : read all sentences and build a HashSet of words, you will have much lesser number of words to search that way, because many words are duplicate. Then call that method for each word in the hashset.

Comment: @Nadd If the answer helped, please consider upvoting/accepting.

Comment: I can't because I must retain every sentence to detect if it is or nott certain.I the sentence contains cue(eg:probably,may,etc), it is uncertain.Is the task for ConLL 2010http://rgai.inf.u-szeged.hu/conll2010st/download.html.  I have choosed the first  training set(Biological training data), so I nedd all sentences because with the dependency graph I can see which word on which depends

Comment: I have voted but the vote can not be displayed because my reputation is less than 15.It is considered like an up vote but can not be displayed